# LINQ query slow - nested Group By and ToList()

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-sql

I have the following linq query that takes 10 seconds or more to run - is there a better way of writing it?  It works, but is just very slow:

```
var searchQuery = (from p in db.Property
where p.PropertyVendorId == loggedInUserId
from aues in db.ApplicationUserEvents
where aues.ApplicationUserEventsPropertyId == p.PropertyId
&& aues.ApplicationUserEventsFeedbackDate != null
group p by new { p.PropertyId, p.PropertyAddress1, p.PropertyAddress2, p.PropertyAddress3, p.PropertyZipOrPostcode } into pg
select new DashboardFeedback
{
    PropertyNumber = pg.FirstOrDefault().PropertyNumber,
    PropertyId = pg.FirstOrDefault().PropertyId,
    PropertyReference = pg.FirstOrDefault().PropertyId,
    PropertyAddress1 = pg.FirstOrDefault().PropertyAddress1,
    PropertyAddress2 = pg.FirstOrDefault().PropertyAddress2,
    PropertyZipOrPostcode = pg.FirstOrDefault().PropertyZipOrPostcode,
    DashboardFeedbackChart = (
          from aues2 in db.ApplicationUserEvents
          where aues2.ApplicationUserEventsPropertyId == pg.FirstOrDefault().PropertyId
          && aues2.ApplicationUserEventsFeedbackDate != null
          from fos in db.FeedbackOptions
          where fos.FeedbackOptionsApplicationUserEventsId == aues2.ApplicationUserEventsId
          from fo in db.FeedbackOption
          where fos.FeedbackOptionsFeedbackOptionId == fo.FeedbackOptionId
          group fo by new { fo.FeedbackOptionName, aues2.ApplicationUserEventsPropertyId } into g
          select new DashboardFeedbackChart
          {
              FeedbackOptionName = g.FirstOrDefault().FeedbackOptionName,
              FeedbackOptionNameCount = g.Count()
          }).ToList<DashboardFeedbackChart>()
}).ToList();
```

- One Property has many ApplicationUserEvents
- One ApplicationUserEvents has many FeedbackOptions
- One FeedbackOptions has one FeedbackOption

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Against what database (and version), what do you see in SQL server? A single query or many queries (use SQL Activity Monitor or Profiler)? Linq²sql is 'old' and hasn't seen any performance improvements in ages.